# Downcasting shared_ptr<Base> to shared_ptr<Derived>?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

***Update:** the shared_ptr in this example is like the one in Boost, but it doesn't support shared_polymorphic_downcast (or dynamic_pointer_cast or static_pointer_cast for that matter)!*

I'm trying to initialize a shared pointer to a derived class without losing the reference count:

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived : public Base { };
shared_ptr<Base> base(new Base());
shared_ptr<Derived> derived;

// error: invalid conversion from 'Base* const' to 'Derived*'
derived = base;
```

So far, so good.  I didn't expect C++ to implicitly convert Base* to Derived*.  However, I do want the functionality expressed by the code (that is, maintaining the reference count while downcasting the base pointer). My first thought was to provide a cast operator in Base so that an implicit conversion to Derived could take place (for pedants: I would check that the down cast is valid, don't worry):

```
struct Base {
  operator Derived* ();
}
// ...
Base::operator Derived* () {
  return down_cast<Derived*>(this);
}
```

Well, it didn't help. It seems the compiler completely ignored my typecast operator. Any ideas how I could make the shared_ptr assignment work? For extra points: what kind of type `Base* const` is?  `const Base*` I understand, but `Base* const`?  What does `const` refer to in this case?

Comment: Why do you need a shared_ptr<Derived>, instead of shared_ptr<Base>?

Comment: Because I want to access functionality in Derived that's not in Base, without cloning the object (I want a single object, referenced by two shared pointers). By the way, why don't the cast operators work?

Answer (score 165):

You can use `dynamic_pointer_cast`. It is supported by `std::shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> base (new Derived());
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived =
               std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived> (base);
```

Documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Also, I don't recommend using cast operator in the base class. Implicit casting like this may become the source of bugs and errors.

*-Update:* If the type is not polymorphic, `std::static_pointer_cast` may be used.

Comment: I didn't understand from the first line that he's not using `std::shared_ptr`. But from the comments of the first answer I inferred that he's not using boost, so he may be using `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: OK. Sorry. He should better clarified that he's using a custom implementation.

Answer (score 51):

I assume you're using `boost::shared_ptr`...  I think you want [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast) or `shared_polymorphic_downcast`.

However, these require polymorphic types.

> what kind of type `Base* const` is? `const Base*` I understand, but `Base* const`? What does `const` refer to in this case?

- `const Base *` is a mutable pointer to a constant `Base`.
- `Base const *` is a mutable pointer to a constant `Base`.
- `Base * const` is a constant pointer to a mutable `Base`.
- `Base const * const` is a constant pointer to a constant `Base`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() { } };   // dynamic casts require polymorphic types
struct Derived : public Base { };

boost::shared_ptr<Base> base(new Base());
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> derived;
derived = boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base);
derived = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base);
derived = boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast<Derived>(base);
```

I'm not sure if it was intentional that your example creates an instance of the base type and casts it, but it serves to illustrate the difference nicely.

The `static_pointer_cast` will "just do it".  This will result in undefined behavior (a `Derived*` pointing at memory allocated for and initialized by `Base`) and will likely cause a crash, or worse.  The reference count on `base` will be incremented.

The `dynamic_pointer_cast` will result in a null pointer.  The reference count on `base` will be unchanged.

The `shared_polymorphic_downcast` will have the same result as a static cast, but will trigger an assertion, rather than seeming to succeed and leading to undefined behavior.  The reference count on `base` will be incremented.

See [(dead link)](http://www.tweakbits.com/articles/sharedptr/index.html):

> Sometimes it is a little hard to decide whether to use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, and you wish you could have a little bit of both worlds. It is well known that dynamic_cast has a runtime overhead, but it is safer, whereas static_cast has no overhead at all, but it may fail silently. How nice it would be if you could use `shared_dynamic_cast` in debug builds, and `shared_static_cast` in release builds. Well, such a thing is already available and is called `shared_polymorphic_downcast`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution depends on Boost functionality that was deliberately excluded from the particular shared_ptr implementation we're using (don't ask why).  As for the const explanation, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: Short of implementing the other `shared_ptr` constructors (taking `static_cast_tag` and `dynamic_cast_tag`), there's not much you can do.  Anything you do outside `shared_ptr` will not be able to manage the refcount.  --  In a "perfect" OO design you can always use the base type, and never need to know nor care what the derived type is, because all its functionality is exposed through base-class interfaces.  Perhaps you just need to re-think why you need to down-cast in the first place.

Comment: @Tim Sylvester: but, C++ is not a "perfect" OO language! :-)  down-casts have their place in a non-perfect OO language

Answer (score 5):

**If somebody gets here with boost::shared_ptr...**

This is how you can downcast to the derived Boost shared_ptr. Assuming Derived inherits from Base.

```
boost::shared_ptr<Base> bS;
bS.reset(new Derived());

boost::shared_ptr<Derived> dS = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived,Base>(bS);
std::cout << "DerivedSPtr  is: " << std::boolalpha << (dS.get() != 0) << std::endl;
```

*Make sure 'Base' class/struct has at least one virtual function. A virtual destructor also works.*

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue this week and my solution do not involve the new kinds of casting available only in the modern c++ (>= 20). I only used reinterpret_cast with a const & of the shared ptr created in between the conversion as shown in the code below:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> basePtr = createBasePtr();
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = reinterpret_cast<const std::shared_ptr<Derived>&>(basePtr);
```