# Validity of casting a Base pointer to a Derived pointer when Derived only adds methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, extend, downcast

First, the question is very similar to 
[downcasting shared pointer to derived class with additional functionality is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284940/downcasting-shared-pointer-to-derived-class-with-additional-functionality-is-t), where there are good answers. But I'd like to have explanation on why this is valid (or not) and when not using shared pointers. So :

```
class Base { /* ... */ };

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void additionnalFunc(int i){ /* access Base members */ }
};

int main(){
Base b;
Derived* d = (Derived*) &b; // or static_cast ?
d->additionnalFunc(3); // works ok.
}
```

This works as expected with gcc. So my question is it safe/valid ? with any compiler or architecture ? if not, why ?

To explain why this question, here is the context.

- I have "Base" objects.
- I can't modify the Base class
- I have a set of templated functions which requires the same interface
  as Base, except a few additional functions.
- I want to be able to use this templated library with my Base objects
- Because of the additional functions, the above is impossible. But
  these functions are trivial to implement from Base.
- Also I want to be as efficient as possible (avoid conversions and
  indirections)

So if the above trick is valid, it could be a good solution...  But maybe there is a better design to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour.  Whether it "works" or not on any given compiler is probably besides the point; you cannot rely on this working in general.<sup>*</sup>

In the scenario you've described, it sounds like the best solution is just to create some free functions that take a `Base` as an argument.  Of course, if the required functionality relies on `protected` members, then you have a problem!  (And I'm not sure there's a good solution, other than to find a way to avoid needing such access.)

---

<sub>* And that's true even if you never change your compiler.  The compiler is free to assume that all code is "correct", so a slight change to your code may trigger an optimization that renders the above trick useless.</sub>

(Of course, I'm not going to to suggest that this will **definitely** happen, merely that it **could**.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand the difference with the question I linked : the 1st answer there says this is valid if Base has a virtual destructor. The only difference I see with my case is the use of shared ptrs, does it really matters ? (also note Derived only adds *methods*, no member, so I expect the same memory layout and thus hope all this is valid ;)

Comment: @rdrien: because in that question, the object in question really is a Derived.