# Base class pointer to Derived class pointer using the already allocated memory

Tags: c++, c++11

Take two classes that both can only be created by `new`. One class is the base and the other is a derivative. The derived class only adds methods.

```
class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{};

Base * b = new Base{}
Derived * d = covert( b );

// - or -

Base * b = new Base{};
convert( b ); // converts Base to Derived
Derived * d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(b);
```

What  I want to do is take the `Base` class data that has been allocated and extend/wrap with the derivative via some method or function, `convert`.

**Update:**
Building for embedded systems memory is scarce, so I am doing everything I can to reduce that amount of memory allocation. I was just wondering if there was a way to just sort of extend the base class already allocated memory and wrap it with the derivative.

**More Updates:**
Although the embedded system is ARM and I am currently using LLVM compiler this might not be true in the future. So a standard compliant way is preferred.

Comment: Nope, in C++ you can't do alchemy (i.e. transmute types). Whatever you do must involve a constructor of `Derived`.

Comment: why not just create the derived object directly? reinterpret_cast<Derived*> might work, if you are lucky, but it would be undefined behaviour

Comment: Base is unwary of the derived class. Have you coded in Java before?

Comment: @PrototypeStark Have you coded in C++?

Comment: @NebulaFox nah I've never looked at C++ code before. Is this java?

Comment: @PrototypeStark no, C++, look at the tags, and if you had looked in a little into C++ then you would know of the `friend` keyword, http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

Comment: @NebulaFox and if you had looked a little deeper, you would know of static_cast<Derived *> :-/

Comment: @PrototypeStark now that sounds more useful, but where is your link explaining why that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question one possible solution is to use aggregation instead of inheritance.

```
class Base
{/*has only the data*/}

class Derived 
{
    Base &base;
    Derived(Base &b) : base(b) {}
    //now methods from derived will use the data members from instance passed in constructor
    //if is possible the Derived needs to be a friend class of Base in case there are no getter for all members
}
```

Instead of reference we can use a smart pointer if necessary.
This way you avoid the cast by constructing a new Derived object which uses the data from the a Base object.

Answer (score 2):

Promoting classes is not possible in C++. What you might want to do is - like you said - wrap `Base` in `Derived`:

```
class BaseInterface { ... };

class DerivedInterface: public BaseInterface { ... };

class Base: public BaseInterface { ... };

class Derived: public DerivedInterface {
private:
  Base* base;
public:
  Derived(Base* useBase): base(useBase) {}
  ~Derived() { delete base; }
  // implement using base
};
```

And use it like that:

```
Base* object = new Base(...);
// use object with base functionality
object = new Derived(object);
// use object with derived functionality
delete object; // free both base and derived memory
```

Answer (score 1):

> The derived class only adds methods.

Then there is no point to that class. At all.

You can use deriving to:

- override `virtual` methods (and thus customize behaviors) => Good
- extend the data of the base class => Bad, code reuse should use composition, still it works

In your particular case ? It's just useless. It does not bring *anything* to the table. If you wish to add new functionalities to your base class, then implement *free functions*. And as a bonus, getting rid of the derived class, you'll also get rid of the need to cast.

Comment: @NebulaFox: In the worst case, we are talking about *Composition*. You could perfectly build a `class Specialized { public: /* methods */ private: Base* _base: };` and use that on the stack, it would work well, takes just as much space as a pointer, and "hide" the base class if that's what you meant (not sure, didn't understand what you meant unfortunately). If you would bring a concrete example of why you think you need a derived class, then I could give a concrete explanation of why you don't ;)

Comment: An example from another type of language is Smalltalk with it's use of categories. A C++ example is class Data. This class has simple methods for accessing data, saving and loading. And say saving and loading takes a block or a function processing the data. The class Data is then split off into different classes such as Music and Image. These classes add methods that look like they override saving and loading but are helper methods with the special block  or function for processing.

Comment: @NebulaFox: but Smalltalk does not have free functions. In C++ you can add functions *outside* of classes.

Comment: but I am encapsulating logic so I do not want *free functions*. What about my C++ example?

Comment: @NebulaFox: do you mean the answer you just gave ? I would say that deleting the content of `base` is slightly evil. As for the functionality, what's wrong with the `Specialized` implementation I proposed above ?

Answer (score 1):

A potential option comes about thanks to C++11

```
class Base
{
  pubilc:
    Data data;

    Base( Base && base ) : data( std::move( base.data ) ) {} 
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  pubilc:
    static Derived * convert( Base *& base )
    {
        Derived * d = new Derived{ std::move( *base ) };
        delete base;

        base = d;
        return d;
    }
 };
```

Although it is not what I hoped for memory-wise it is only a small hit, as far as I am aware. By using the move construct, the only overhead is the creation of a new `Derived` object before deleting the old `Base` object.

There should be a check before anything is done, but this will do for now.

Comment: you need a modern compiler. Your LLVM should be OK, but upgrading to latest version may help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper class which is a friend of the base class, and add extra functions to that, e.g.

```
class Base 
{
   friend class BaseHelper;
   // ....
};
class BaseHelper
{
    public:
    // all functions can access data into Base objects:
    void f(const Base& b) const; // can only read data in b, not change it
    void g(Base& b); // can change data in b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Derived *d =static_cast<Derived *>(b); //? :-/
```

[Here is one explanation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fkeyword_static_cast.htm)

[Another explanation](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t646109-does-c-spec-allow-static_cast-of-polymorphic-objects.html)

[Much more detailed explanation of what's happening under the hood](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12935/What-static_cast-is-actually-doing)

UPDATE:

[Stack Overflow - Downcasting using the static_cast in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/downcasting-using-the-static-cast-in-c)

[Downcasting in C++ using static_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/79249/)

SPECIFICATION:

> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be
>   converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a class
>   derived (clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), cv2 is the same
>   cvqualification as, or greater cvqualification than, cv1, and B is not
>   a virtual base class of D. The null pointer value (4.10) is converted
>   to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the rvalue of
>   type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of
>   an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing
>   object of type D. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

FOR LLVM ONLY:

http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html - ALLOWS DOWNCASTING(is not undefined  behavior, since it doesn't use C++ RTTI).

There is no standard-compliant way of downcasting:

```
class Parent{
    public: void gotoWork(){ cout << doWork(); }
};

class Child: public Parent{
     public: void gotoSchool(){ cout << attendClasses();}
};

Parent *p = new Parent();
Child *ch = static_cast<Child*> p;
//now child has to go work? :-(
```

**EDIT**

> Apart from all other ways, why not put two objects? one of type "Base"
>   and another of type "Derived" into a UNION?
>
> PS: Its language-specification conformant.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but they do not explain the particular case. Your first link explains what `static_cast` is which is fair enough for anyone else reading this. The second link doesn't add much. But the third link has the gold showing you particular example.

Comment: One more thing, when you do the `static_cast` all methods will work on the `Derived` object `d`?

Comment: Isn't that undefined behaviour?

Comment: It is an undefined behavior. But works on all compilers. Its undefined because C++ specification doesn't talk about it. Works on all compilers equally.

Comment: @PrototypeStark:  **If** the rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `B`” points to a `B` that **is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`**, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. **Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.** I think that the specification is pretty clear... Just because it's working now means nothing, gcc 4.7 broke a lot of code that worked with gcc 4.6 by being more aggressive in its exploitation of the undefined behavior rules.

Comment: @PrototypeStark I think MatthieuM. is pointing at is, that it may work now but there is nothing to say it will continue to work. So a more standard way of doing things at least guarantees that it will not suddenly break

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Yes. Recommanding taking advantage of undefined behavior is like recommanding playing with fire. You may not have burned yourself yet, but it's still a dangerous game.

Comment: @NebulaFox since you mentioned Embedded System, what is the microprocessor/microcontroller you're using and what compiler?

Comment: the processor is ARM and I am allowed to use LLVM

Comment: @NebulaFox, LLVM doesn't follow C++'s RTTI. Is more flexible and allows you to downcast this way. :-). http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html

Comment: @people-downcasting Please mention WHY you're downcasting anything. If you're a language Nazi go elsewhere. We are here to solve REAL WORLD problems not be language conformant.

Comment: @NebulaFox people here seem to be ignorant downvoters. Why don't you modify the question to state explicitly the compiler and processor in use. while I change my answer to include links specifically for LLVM. Or else this "accepted" answer will end up with -ve votes.

Comment: The problem is the code may be moved to another embedded system that might not get benefits of LLVM annoyingly. I will un-accept this answer. Thanks for everything though.

Comment: @NebulaFox Unbelievable. Why aren't they using LLVM on another embedded system?

Comment: @NebulaFox there is no standard-complaint downcast available because its a breach of basic object oriented programming.

Comment: @PrototypeStark there is an embedded system that only uses gcc. Not everyone has gotten on the LLVM bandwagon. Seriously sucks.

Comment: @NebulaFox here is one for GCC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358143/downcasting-shared-ptrbase-to-shared-ptrderived

Comment: @PrototypeStark:  
        class B {  
          int a, &b;  
          B(): a(1), b(a) {}  
        };  
        class D: public B {  
          int c;  
          D(): c(2) {}  
          int get() { return b+c; }  
        };  
I didn't downvote and I hope I'm not too ignorant, but how exactly exactly is your static_cast going to report `d->get() == 3` without memory violation??

Comment: @Antoine do you understand that you need to create an OBJECT of type D for the constructor to be called? Here he isn't trying to CREATE AN OBJECT OF D, he is just trying to call some methods in D as well as B and SQUEEZE the object, much like what unions do, he is extending the object, NOT CREATING ANOTHER.

Comment: @NebulaFox answering Antoine, I got an idea. Why don't you put two objects, one of type Base and another of type Derived into a union? You get a squeezed object anyway?

Comment: @PrototypeStark that's interesting

Comment: and for all the specifications nazi, its standard compliant.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Yes. The problem here is that since D may be bigger than B, static_cast may be forced to realloc the object to another location, in which case all logic assuming an object has const address is void (int &b in my code).
If D has no data and there are no virtual methods, you should do `(Derived*)(void*)b` instead of `static_cast<Derived*>(b)` since you can't be sure static_cast will not change the address.

Comment: I am throwing this in for good measure http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=556

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the many answers that I have, the common consensus is that I should do what I said and actually wrap my `Base` class within the `Derived` class. The reason I was not doing this is I would lose a particular behaviour you get with inheritance. This behaviour is setting a pointer of the `Derived` class to a pointer of type `Base`, which will happen after I did some sort of conversion that will make the `Base` class transform into the `Derived` class.

A did stumble on a solution of my [own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12976824/398640) - although apparently it may not compile - and have had many other [good ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973834/398640) as well. In the end, I was a bit slow to realise that because, for my case, my `Derived` class does not override any virtual methods there was [no benefit of using inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975116/398640). The best way is indeed to to use composition.

```
class Base
{
    // some nice implementation
};

class Derived
{
  public:
    Derived( Base && base )
    {
        this->_base = base;
    }

    Base & base()
    {
        return _base;
    }

  private:
    Base _base;
};
```