# std::unique_ptr<T[]> API prohibits derived-to-base pointer conversions

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

In *Modern Effective C++*, "Iterm 19: Use `std::shared_ptr` for shared-ownership resource management.", Page 133-134, it says:

> std::shared_ptr supports derived-to-base pointer conversions that make
>   sense for single objects, but that open holes in the type system when
>   applied to arrays. (For this reason, the std::unique_ptr API
>   prohibits such conversions.)

What's the meaning of "open holes in the type system"?

Why would `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` API prohibit derived-to-base pointer conversions?

And how could it prohibit the conversions?

Comment: [Array of Derived is not a kind-of array of Base](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/proper-inheritance.html#faq-21.4)

Comment: Actually, I'm going to drop my answer, because (a) of the dupe, and (b) because I don't *think* it answers the *specific* question about type system holes.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why do you think you answer doesn't address the questions? The answers to [potential dupe I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358143/downcasting-shared-ptrbase-to-shared-ptrderived?rq=1) did not mention underlying problem i.e. memory layout, which you nicely explained. You only missed the mechanism to prohibit the conversion, where clang for `unique_ptr` seem to explicitly use SFINAE https://godbolt.org/z/LGfULn

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**A hole in the type system** is whenever the compiler doesn't catch when a type is cast to another incompatible type.

Imagine you have two simple classes:

```
class A
{
    char i;
};

class B : public A
{
    char j;
};
```

Let's for simplicity ignore things like padding etc. and assume that objects of type `A` are 1 byte and objects of type `B` are 2 byte.

Now when you have an array of type `A` or an array of type `B`, they will look like this:

```
A a[4]:

=================
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-------|-------|
| i | i | i | i |
=================

B b[4]:

=================================
|   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| i | j | i | j | i | j | i | j |
=================================
```

Now imagine you have pointers to these arrays and then cast one to the other, this would obviously lead to problems:

```
a cast to B[4]:

=================================
|   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| i | j | i | j | x | x | x | x |
=================================
```

The first two objects in the array will interpret the `i` member of the 2nd and 4th `A` as their `j` member. The 2nd and 3rd member access unallocated memory.

```
b cast to A[4]:

=================
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-------|-------|
| i | i | i | i | x | x | x | x |
=================
```

Here it's the other way around, all 4 objects now alternatingly interpret the `i` and the `j` of 2 `B` instances as their `i` members. And half of the array is lost.

Now imagine deleting such a casted array. Which destructors will be called? What memory will be freed? You are in deep hell at this point.

**But wait, there's more.**

Imagine you have 3 classes like this:

```
class A
{
    char i;
};

class B1 : public A
{
    float j;
};

class B2 : public A
{
    int k;
};
```

And now you create an array of `B1` pointers:

```
B1* b1[4];
```

If you cast that array to an array of `A` pointers you could think, *"well this is fine, right"*?

```
A** a = <evil_cast_shenanigans>(b1);
```

I mean, you can safely access each member as pointer to `A`:

```
char foo = a[0]->i; // This is valid
```

But what you can also do, is this:

```
a[0] = new B2{};   // Uh, oh.
```

This is a valid assignment, no compiler will complain, but you must not forget that we are actually working on an array that was created as an array of pointers to `B1` objects. And it's first member now points at a `B2` object, which you can now access as `B1` without the compiler saying a thing.

```
float bar = b1[0]->j;   // Ouch.
```

So again you are in deep hell, and the compiler won't be able to warn you, except if that upcasting isn't allowed in the first place.

**Why would std::unique_ptr API prohibit derived-to-base pointer conversions?**

I hope the above explanations give good reasons why.

**How could it prohibit the conversions?**

It simply doesn't provide any API to do conversions. The shared_ptr API has conversion functions like `static_pointer_cast`, the unique_ptr API doesn't.